# Markup in the allboard "hot questions" list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange-button

The all-boards "hot questions" list that you can access if you click the StackExchange button at the top left doesn't support tex markup, which leads to some akward looking hot topics.

In particular, with the rising popularity of tex.stackexchange and math.stackexchange coming out of beta, they are appearing more and more often in the all-board hot topics list. Math especially breaks the feed, since the markup for most mathematical expressions is pretty tex heavy.

seeing something like $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2}$ in the topic feed doesn't look pretty

Answer (score 2):

MathJax takes about one full megabyte of dependencies, so it won't be rendering anywhere but on those sites any time soon.

Comment: I remember a request here about replacing code blocks with '[code]' in question descriptions on the questions page, maybe something similar would be useful here?

Comment: Could MathJax be used on stackexchange.com site, so that once you click through on the hot questions you see it right?