# Are the questions with TeX markup in titles excluded from Hot Network Questions?

Tags: support, title, hot-questions, mathjax

Over the years, users of non-MathJax-enabled sites complained about unparsed TeX markup in the titles of Hot Network Questions coming from Mathematics and other MathJax-enabled sites. For example:

1. [Markup in the allboard "hot questions" list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68961/)
2. [Unreadable LaTeX in hot questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108166/)
3. [Suppress Hot Questions containing MathJax markup on non-MathJax sites homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210215/)

I haven't found any announcement of this change, but it **appears** that questions whose titles contain TeX markup are being excluded from Hot Network Questions. Evidence:

- I don't see markup in any questions present on the [list](https://stackexchange.com/)
- When I saw a question with the title "Real Analysis- Calculus" on the Hot Network Questions  list and renamed it to [something sensible](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/885871/), it disappeared when I refreshed the list.

I hope someone from SE can confirm or refute the above. If this is true, then the feature requests numbered 2 and 3 above have been fulfilled.

---

Tangential: I know all about MathJax being heavy, but if it was enabled on stackexchange.com site (which I assume does not get the traffic of SO), the questions could still be shown there... (I won't make this a feature request until the status of the above is clarified).

Comment: related: [Does Stack Exchange record when particular question enters and leaves hot list?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238445/165773)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Sklivvz confirmed that such questions are excluded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239869/is-unicode-in-hot-network-questions-question-titles-allowed/239879?noredirect=1#comment785881_239879):

> the problem is simply that we don't want to turn on MathJax everywhere, most notably on StackOverflow, so those titles don't render correctly